# Highcharts.chart() in Angular

Tags: angular-highcharts

How should I be using Highcharts in Angular?

I imported it

`import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts'`

then tried

`Highcharts.chart(tag, options)`

where `tag` is a string `id` of an HTML element, and `options` is the plot options. But typescript claims there is no such overload for `chart()`, or more explicitly

`Type 'string' has no properties in common with type 'Options'`

However, when I peeked into `chart()`, I quickly noticed that there sure is one, specifically one that take `renderTo` as its first argument.

Why typescript lying? Or more likely, what am I missing?